# Split button for catalog product admin page

Tags: magento2, products

I have created some buttons on catalog product admin page. I would like to group them in a dropdown (split) button like the **Add Product** button. Can you please help?

[image]

My product_listing.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="productssync" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">productssync</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync All Products</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/productssync</item>
            </item>
            <item name="basicdetailssync" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">basicdetailssync</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync Basic Details</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/basicdetailssync</item>
            </item>
            <item name="extracategoriessync" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">extracategoriessync</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync Extra Categories</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/extracategoriessync</item>
            </item>
            <item name="inventorysync" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">inventorysync</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync Inventory</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/inventorysync</item>
            </item>
            <item name="relationssync" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">relationssync</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync Relations</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/relationssync</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton` for `class_name`.

In case you need to create additional button class

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

```php
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sync" xsi:type="string">Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Control\Button\Sync</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Ui/Component/Control/Button/Sync.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Control\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Sync implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    protected Context $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getButtonData(): array
    {
        return [
            'id'           => 'acme_sync',
            'label'        => __('Sync'),
            'class'        => 'secondary',
            'button_class' => 'sync',
            'class_name'   => SplitButton::class,
            'options'      => $this->getOptions(),
            'sort_order'   => 5,
        ];
    }

    protected function getOptions(): array
    {
        return [
            'productssync' => [
                'label' => __('Sync All Products'),
                'default' => true,
                'onclick' => $this->getOnClickUrl('sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/productssync')
            ],
            'basicdetailssync' => [
                'label' => __('Sync Basic Details'),
                'onclick' => $this->getOnClickUrl('sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/basicdetailssync')
            ],
            'extracategoriessync' => [
                'label' => __('Sync Extra Categories'),
                'onclick' => $this->getOnClickUrl('sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/extracategoriessync')
            ],
            'inventorysync' => [
                'label' => __('Sync Inventory'),
                'onclick' => $this->getOnClickUrl('sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/inventorysync')
            ],
            'relationssync' => [
                'label' => __('Sync Relations'),
                'onclick' => $this->getOnClickUrl('sandy_erpsyncbuttons/product/relationssync')
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function getOnClickUrl(string $path, array $params = []): string
    {
        return sprintf("setLocation('%s')",
            $this->context->getEscaper()->escapeUrl(
                $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($path, $params)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

You can set `default` for one of children, and if you are not set default - noone action will be fired on click without select action.

[image: Result]

For reorder **Add product** button you need to add custom CSS, in case `SplitButton` class add `actions-split` class to button container. Alternative is create custom class and extend `SplitButton`, but anyway you need to add some extra styles.

Some example of CSS in `less`

```less
    .actions-split.sync {
        .lib-vendor-prefix-order(1);
        &:hover, &.active, &._active {
            box-shadow: none;
        }
        button.secondary {
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            border-color: #adadad;
            color: #514943;
            text-shadow: none;
            &:hover {
                box-shadow: none;
                background-color: #dbdbdb;
            }
            &:after {
                border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.