# Club buttons in a drop down - m2 admin

Tags: magento2

I have created buttons for a page in m2 admin. Please see below screenshot.

[image]

I've used following xml code at /view/adminhtml/ui_component/buttons.xml:

```
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="addAllProductsForSync" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">addAllProductsForSync</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add all Products For Sync</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addAllProductsForSync</item>
            </item>
            <item name="EnqueueAllInProgress" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">EnqueueAllInProgress</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enqueue All In Progress</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/backToQueue</item>
            </item>
            <item name="clearQueue" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">clear</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Clear Queue</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/clear</item>
            </item>
            <item name="clearEntities" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">clear</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Clear Entities Sync</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/clearentities</item>
            </item>
            <item name="truncateQueue" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">truncate</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Truncate Queue</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/truncate</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

As you see, buttons are taking much space. So, can I club them into a drop down or something similar without break the existing functionality?

Your help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358625/split-button-for-catalog-product-admin-page) Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @AzizKapasi It's worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome, can you please upvote the comment, it'll help others with same issue

Comment: Sure @AzizKapasi, I'll do it. Could you help me in my latest question? 

Link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371403/adding-a-version-to-a-module-extension-in-magento-2-admin